# jenkins file readjson key exists check

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using readjson object out of jenkins pipeline to query bitbucket and jira rest api.
I need to make sure specific json key `(values[n].properties.jira-key)` pre-exists prior to taking its value to further logic.

I found the following methods crash:

- `commits.values[n].properties.hasOwnProperty('jira-key')`
- `commits.values[n].properties.containsKey('jira-key')`

Has anyone checked key pre-exists in json out of jenkinsfile?

Comment: Here we are ...

for (int m = 0; m < commits.values.size(); m++) {
      if (commits.values[m].properties.toString().contains("date")){
...
       }
}

Answer (score 1):

I use this method:

```
script {
  def jsonFile = readJSON file: "data.json"
  def varInJson = ""
  if (jsonFile.actions[0].properties.toString().contains("userId")) {
    varInJson = "${jsonFile.actions[0].userId}
  } else {
    varInJson = "Variable doesn't exist"
  }
echo varInJson
}
```

It gives me the value of the userId key if that key exists.

Answer (score 0):

I'd refrain from converting the properties to a string and looking for the sought-for key in the string representation. See below for why.

Finding the right way is (as so often) not as easy. Looking at the [readJSON step implementation](https://github.com/jenkinsci/pipeline-utility-steps-plugin/blob/37cd11712f142fd800eb7f5ba5773182857178d8/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/pipeline/utility/steps/json/ReadJSONStepExecution.java#L87), this uses the [json-lib JSONSerializer](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONSerializer.html#toJSON(java.lang.Object)) under the hood.

So in this case, `properties` should be an instance of [JSONObject](http://json-lib.sourceforge.net/apidocs/jdk15/net/sf/json/JSONObject.html) which inherits from [Map](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.html). Map has a `containsKey` method to checking if a given key is mapped.

So the following works for the Jenkins 2.319.2 installation I had available for testing:

```java
if (jsonFile.commits[0].properties.containsKey('jira-key')) {
    ...
}
```

The following plain Groovy example illustrates the difference between searching for the key in the string representation and using `containsKey` to look specifically at the keys of the map:

```java
@Grapes(
  @Grab(group='org.kohsuke.stapler', module='json-lib', version='2.4-jenkins-3')
)
import net.sf.json.JSONSerializer

var jsonData = JSONSerializer.toJSON("""[
    {"example": "jira-key"},
    {"jira-key": "JIRABUG-42"}
]""")

var matchByKey = jsonData.findAll { it -> it.containsKey('jira-key') }
var matchByString = jsonData.findAll { it -> it.toString().contains('jira-key') }

println("Matches using containsKey: ${matchByKey}")
println("Matches using toString: ${matchByString}")
```